# How to pass an array of conditions in mongokit find query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongokit

How can i pass *array* of condtions in **mongokit find** query.

Untill now , i am implementing queries like :

```
data = db.entry.find({'title':{'$regex':'test'},'status':{'$regex':'active'}}).limit(3);
```

Condtions are bound to increase. Is there any way i can pass an array of conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conditions = {'title':{'$regex':'test'},'status':{'$regex':'active'} ..... other conditions }
data = db.entry.find(conditions).limit(3);
```